# How to run mongodb queries in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am using below query to get data from the `collection` in `mongodb`

```
db.testcoll.aggregate([​
  { $unwind :'$data'},​
  { $match : {'type': 'data1', "my_id" : "44ef", 'data.time': { $gte : "2018-07-07 00:00:30" , $lte : "2018-07-08 00:57:30"} }},​
  { $project : { _id:0, my_id: '$my_id', time : '$data.time', value : '$data.value'} }​
])
```

Running the above query in `MongoDb`, I get appropriate results. Now I am writing a small `python` script where I need to run the same query.

```
query = ([​
  { '$unwind' :'$data'},​
  { '$match' : {'type': 'data1', "my_id" : "44ef", 'data.time': { '$gte' : "2018-07-07 00:00:30" , '$lte' : "2018-07-08 00:57:30"} }},​
  { '$project' : { '_id':0, 'my_id': '$my_id', 'time' : '$data.time', 'value' : '$data.value'} }​
])

document = testcoll.find(query)
for i in document:
    print(i)
```

It shows document values as `None` in debugger and thus throws error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can I run the query in python. Thanks

Comment: python driver should have documentation on mongodb site, with examples and everything. Have you checked that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the same query of mongo in python to run**

```
query = [
  { '$unwind' :'$data'},​
  { '$match' : {'type': 'data1', "my_id" : "44ef", 'data.time': { '$gte' : "2018-07-07 00:00:30" , '$lte' : "2018-07-08 00:57:30"} }},​
  { '$project' : { '_id':0, 'my_id': '$my_id', 'time' : '$data.time', 'value' : '$data.value'} }​
]
document = testcoll.aggregate(query)
for i in document:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework) states, you need to use the `aggregate` function.

```
query = ([​
  { '$unwind' :'$data'},​
  { '$match' : {'type': 'data1', "my_id" : "44ef", 'data.time': { '$gte' : "2018-07-07 00:00:30" , '$lte' : "2018-07-08 00:57:30"} }},​
  { '$project' : { '_id':0, 'my_id': '$my_id', 'time' : '$data.time', 'value' : '$data.value'} }​
])

document = testcoll.aggregate(query)
for i in document:
    print(i)
```

Also, seems you are new to pymongo but something to look into. PyMongo is great but every interaction you make with it is blocking. Consider using [Motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html) it allows for async/await (*or even Flask if that's what you use*) 
Almost all the same functions work with it but they are non blocking.

With motor it would just become:

```
document = await testcoll.aggregate(query)
```